# PHP - Local vs UTC Time Comparison with Timezone Offset

Tags: php, date, utc

Given a variable unix timestamp and a fixed timezone offset in seconds, how can you tell if local time is past 8am.

For example, take the following variables:

```
$timestamp = time();
$timezone_offset = -21600;  //i think that's -8hrs for pacific time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(date("H", $timestamp + $timezone_offset) >= 8){
    // do something
}
```

Assuming you consider even a millisecond past 8:00:00 is "past 8am".

Comment: thanks, this does it.  so if i wanted to add an 15 minute buffer, then I'd get the output of date using "H" and minutes using "i" and compare separately?

Answer (score 0):

You set your timezone in PHP using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date-default-timezone-set) and then use PHP's datetime functions like date or [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object to check the time according to the set timezone. PHP will do the right thing for you and adjust the time to the specified timezone.

```
$timestamp = 1354794201;
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); // set time zone to UTC
if (date("H", $timestamp) >= 8) { // check to see if it's past 8am in UTC
    echo "This time stamp is past 8 AM in " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";
}

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); // change time zone
if (date("H", $timestamp) >= 8) { // Check to see if it's past 8am in EST
    echo "This time stamp is past 8 AM in " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";
}
```

Output from this code

```
/* This time stamp is past 8 AM in UTC */
```

You can do the same thing with DateTime as well...

```
$timestamp = 1354794201;
$date = new DateTime("@{$timestamp}"); // create the DateTime object using a Unix timestamp
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC")); // set time zone to UTC
if ($date->format("H") >= 8) { // check to see if it's past 8am in UTC
    echo "This time stamp is past 8 AM in {$date->getTimezone()->getName()}\n";
}

$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/New_York")); // change time zone
if ($date->format("H") >= 8) { // Check to see if it's past 8am in EST
    echo "This time stamp is past 8 AM in {$date->getTimezone()->getName()}\n";
}
```

Output from the above code is also...

```
/* This time stamp is past 8 AM in UTC */
```

Unix time is time zone agnostic. That's the point of using Unix time as a transport layer. You never have to worry about time zones until it comes time to translate your time stamp from Unix time to a formatted date.

Comment: thanks for the time to write this up.  although I am specifically looking to use timezone offset in seconds.